# WITH ROLLUP not showing sum

Tags: mysql, mariadb

```
SELECT a.Store,
       t.CM 
FROM sales_data a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT Store, SUM(no_of_bill) AS CM
    FROM cash_memo c
     WHERE c.Bill_Date < '2018-02-28'
    GROUP BY Store
) t USING (Store) 
GROUP BY a.Store WITH ROLLUP
```

gives me the below result:

[query result][1]

I am not sure whats wrong that I am not getting the sum of 'CM' when using ROLLUP

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Your query is syntactically invalid SQL and so it should fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rollup needs to be with the `group by`.  Try this:

```
SELECT Store, SUM(no_of_bill) AS CM
FROM cash_memo c
WHERE c.Bill_Date < '2018-02-28'
GROUP BY Store WITH ROLLUP;
```

Your query should fail with a syntax error because `CM` is not aggregated in the outer query and is not in the `GROUP BY`.

If you phrased the logic correctly, it would be:

```
SELECT a.Store, SUM(t.CM)
```

This would work and the `ROLLUP` would do what you expect.

Note:  The `JOIN` seems unnecessary for the query.  But if you really want it, you can just include it in the above query with no subquery.

Comment: @BrajeshSharma . . . Is there a reason you unaccepted this answer?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `GROUP BY` in the outer query without doing any aggregation.
Join the 2 tables, aggregate on the resultset returned by the join and use `ROLLUP`:

```
SELECT s.Store, SUM(c.no_of_bill) AS CM 
FROM sales_data s INNER JOIN cash_memo c
ON c.Store = s.Store
WHERE c.Bill_Date < '2018-02-28'
GROUP BY s.Store WITH ROLLUP
```